# filename start with *

Tags: bash

I've got script, it must go through files to get specific lines from them.
Filename get from variable, for example $FILENAME and we've got such situation:

cat /path/$FILENAME

but when `FILENAME==*.some.file` there is a problem. File `*.some.file` really exist, but cat lists all files by mask `*.some.file` (`first.some.file` `second.some.file` `*.some.file` `fourth.some.file` and so on)
single quotes on path prevent include of variable.

Any ideas how to `cat` (or `grep`) only one `*.some.file`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double quotes. This will expand the variable, but not any embedded wildcards.

```
cat /path/"$FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cat "/path/to/$FILENAME"
```

will not expand `*` to a glob.

Answer (score 2):

`cat \*.some.file` will escape the `*` so it's treated as a literal character.

Also `cat '*.some.file'` will have a similar effect. In both cases, it prevents bash from expanding the `*` to a list of matching files.